# Como recibir imagenes de sharepoint con api rest en Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

SHAREPOINT: Estoy intentando obtener en C# imagenes de una lista de sharepoint, las intento recibir en un string pero no me permite. La lista tiene un titulo de imagen, descripcion de ella y la imagen.

Las quiero guardar en base de datos local; la solicitud va asi:

```
SharePointSiteURL + 
"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OutServices')/items?$filter=Modified ge DateTime'" +
lastDate.Value.ToString("O") + "'");
```

En el model la e intentado recibir asi:

```
[JsonProperty("Image")]
public string image { get; set; }
```

Lo intento recibir en un string, puesto que viene como cadena de texto en el ODATA, de no venir asi, como podria recibirlo?

Lo unico que no puedo recibir es la imagen.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la sugerencia.
Ahorita lo edito

Comment: Con gusto Joel, te recomiendo por favor no colocar cosas como "ayuda por favor!!" realmente no es necesario en la pregunta. He colocad una respuesta, espero te sirva. Si tienes inquietud, te pido actualizar la pregunta con mas información. Coloca qué retorna la consulta `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OutServices')/...` , por ejemplo.

Comment: Hola Mauricio. Mira que lo que es la imegen lo que me retorna solamente es la url de ella. Sabes como hacer que con esa url, yo pueda descargar la imagen como string para guardarla en la base de datos? . Gracias de antemano por el tiempo que te tomas en contestar.

Comment: Joel, tendrías que descargar la imagen en una carpeta física, luego convertir esa imagen a string, pero no se si es una buena práctica. Cuando dices "guardar imagen como string" ¿te refieres a [Base64](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Comment: Si, guardarla tipo Base64.
Te comento; la informacion la descargo debido a que quiero que mi app funcione con o sin internet(simplemente mostrar informacion al usuario, incluyendo imagenes).

Comment: mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337488/4092887) acerca de cómo guardar una imagen de una URL o busca `xamarin forms download image`. por lo que veo en los [foros de Xamarin también hay información](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_an_image/). Investiga.

Comment: Quetal. Estuve ya anteriormente revisando el post, pero te la guarda en una ruta(carpeta), y no en una db.

Comment: Joel, ya tienes un paso, ahora, en esa carpeta, puedes usar algo para convertir la imagen en base64. ¿Ya miraste esta [respuesta en los foros de Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27743/image-to-base64-conversion)? cuando tengas el base64, puedes después guardarlo en base de datos. ¿sabes como guardar la imagen, cierto?, si no es así, debes investigar, porque con el debido respeto, no te van a hacer la tarea.

Comment: Ok, gracias por orientarme.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, debes agregar qué campos quieres traer de la lista `OutServices`

Actualmente tiene esto:

```
"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OutServices')/items?$filter=Modified ge..."
```

Pero deberías colocarlo así:

```
"_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OutServices')/items?$select=Title,Description,FileRef&$filter=Modified ge..."
```

En donde:

- **Title** es el título/nombre de la imagen.
- **Description** es la descripción de la imagen.
- **FileRef** es la ruta absoluta de la imagen.

Comment: Hola Mauricio.
Fijate que la consulta me la realiza perfectamente, los campos Title y Description los recibo correctamente y los almaceno en la DB, pero la imegen es la unica que me genera el inconveniente. Al parecer puedo recibirla con este tipo:
    Xamarin.Forms.Image image, ahora necesito convertirla a string, pero no me permite convertirlo de la manera tradicional de C#, ya que el tipo Image es diferente a     Xamarin.Forms.Image image, sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: @JoelCaballero, ahora veo que el problema no es tanto SharePoint sino con conversión de la imagen en Xamarin. La verdad yo no se pero, revisa esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41766823/4092887). Si no lo has intentado, busca en Google a ver qué encuentras - yo de Xamarin no se. Siento no poder ayudarte mas. Saludos y suerte